# What does this mean and how to solve it?

Tags: geometry

The equation described on the chord $3x + y + 5 = 0$ of the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 16$ as a diameter, is:

**(A)** $x^2 + y^2 + 3x + y - 2 = 0$

**(B)** $x^2 + y^2 + 3x + y - 22 = 0$

**(C)** $x^2 + y^2 + 3x + y + 1 = 0$

**(D)** $x^2 +y ^2 + 3x +y - 11 = 0$

Answer (score 0):

They want the equation of the red circle in the picture below.

I agree that is badly written.

I had said:

> Given line $3x+y+5=0$ and circle $x^2+y^2=16$ call $A$ and $B$ their intersection points. Find the equation of the circle having $AB$ as diameter.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It helped a lot!